# Filter info in Atlassian Confluence

Tags: postgresql, confluence, confluence-macros

I am using the JIRA issue/filter macro in Atlassian Confluence.

I am trying to figure out where the filter details are stored in postgres server for Atlassian Confluence.

Can someone help me with it ?

Answer (score 0):

@thenewbee, the filter usually is based on the JQL query filter from integrated JIRA, so you can copy this query to JIRA and find out the details.